# Error inesperado en spinner de Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

estoy intentando implementar un Spinner, pero a la hora de desplegar solo me aparece el primer elemento de todos los que me debería de aparecer en el spinner. 
Por ejemplo, si es un spinner de curriculos de personas en el que aparece nombre foto y texto, solo me aparecería al desplegar solo el primero y no todos.
Aquí os dejo mi código:

//MAIN

```
package com.example.tonij.a4bimplementaelusomascorrientes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<Persona> listaDePersonas= new ArrayList<>();
private Spinner spinner;
private SpinnerPersonas sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        llenarArray();

        spinner= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        sp= new SpinnerPersonas(this, listaDePersonas);
        spinner.setAdapter(sp);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }
    public void llenarArray(){
        int[] arrayImagenes={R.drawable.persona1,R.drawable.persona2,R.drawable.persona3,R.drawable.persona4};
        String[] arrayNombres= {"Ana, Jonathan, Pablo, Alberto"};
        String[] arrayApellidos={"Sanchez","Losa","Santos","Marti"};
        String[] arrayEdad={"22","24","18","28"};
        String[] arrayEstudios={"Ninguno.","Teleco.","Bachiller.","Marketing."};
        String[] arrayTrabajos={"Ninguno.","Inspector de telecomunicaciones.","Dependiente.","Asistente telefonico."};

        for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
            listaDePersonas.add( new Persona(arrayImagenes[i],
                    arrayNombres[i],
                    arrayApellidos[i],arrayEdad[i],arrayEstudios[i],arrayTrabajos[i]));
        }


    }
}
```

//CLASE DEL SPINNER

```
package com.example.tonij.a4bimplementaelusomascorrientes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SpinnerPersonas extends ArrayAdapter<Persona> {
    public SpinnerPersonas(Context context, ArrayList<Persona> listaPersonas){
        super(context,0,listaPersonas);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
    public View initView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.spinner,parent,false
            );
        }
        ImageView imagen= convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagenSpiner);
        Persona persona= getItem(position);

        if(persona!=null){
            imagen.setImageResource(persona.getImg());}
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

//CLASE PERSONA (EL OBJETO QUE IMPLEMENTA EL SPINNER)

```
package com.example.tonij.a4bimplementaelusomascorrientes;

public class Persona {
    private int img;
    private String nombre, apellidos, edad, estudios, trabajo;

    public Persona(int img, String nombre, String apellidos, String edad, String estudios, String trabajo){
        this.img= img;
        this.nombre= nombre;
        this.apellidos= apellidos;
        this.edad= edad;
        this.estudios= estudios;
        this.trabajo= trabajo;
    }

    //GETTERS Y SETTERS
    public int getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(int img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(String edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getEstudios() {
        return estudios;
    }

    public void setEstudios(String estudios) {
        this.estudios = estudios;
    }

    public String getTrabajo() {
        return trabajo;
    }

    public void setTrabajo(String trabajo) {
        this.trabajo = trabajo;
    }

}
```

//LAYOUT DEL SPINNER

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nombre"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Apellidos"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Edad"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imagenSpiner"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

//LAYOUT DEL MAIN

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

MUCHAS GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO <3

Comment: Aun le quedan cosas por matizar, como el listener del spinner, pero eso ignorarlo, aun estoy acabandolo, solo es ese error en concreto, que no tengo ni idea de por que sale así XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo revisar este ciclo en la clase `Main`.

```
for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
    listaDePersonas.add( new Persona(arrayImagenes[i],
    arrayNombres[i],
    arrayApellidos[i],arrayEdad[i],arrayEstudios[i],arrayTrabajos[i]));
}
```

Solo se hace una vez y creo que deberías hacerlo por la cantidad de personas que tengas en uno de los arreglos de arriba.

Comment: Ahhhhh joder jajaja, vale tio, si, es eso.

Comment: Una cosa, estoy mirandolo y cuando incremento el bucle a 4 veces me salta un outOfBounds de los que salen cuando te pasas del tamaño del vector, pero en ningun momento veo yo que se salga. Sabes que puede ser?

Comment: Vale, el array de nombres tenia mal definido todo, ya está resuelto, grácias por tu ayuda

Comment: Para eso estamos